# Get the NOT IN values into an array in postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am looking to obtain a set of results where I receive a user_id and a collection of books that the user HAS NOT reviewed. I would like the following as the required output:

| user_id | Array of books not reviewed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {Array of books not reviewed} |
| 2 | {Array of books not reviewed}. |

Currently there are two tables that this query would require to be pulled from. One contains "reviews" that possesses the user_id of the review, and the book_id that the user HAS reviewed. The book_id is a foreign key to the the "books" table where the total list of books is contained. Therefore for each user_id in the output,  I would require the total list of books, excluding the ones that have been reviewed per user.

See the insert statements below for the reviews and books tables:

Reviews tables -

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
    review_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    rating INT CHECK (rating BETWEEN 0 AND 10),
    review_text TEXT,
    book_id INT REFERENCES books(id),
    user_id INT
);
```

Example of a snippet of the table data:

| review_id | rating | book_id. | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 | 3 |

Books table -

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    price_in_pence INTEGER,
    quantity_in_stock INTEGER
);
```

Example of a snippet of books data:

| id | title | price_in_pence | quantity_in_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bookname | 549 | 12 |
| 2 | LOTR | 799 | 9 |

I have tried the following query, however this is not dynamic and only works per user_id entered (identified below using '**'):

```
SELECT r.user_id, 
       array( SELECT b.title 
              FROM books b 
              WHERE b.id NOT IN (SELECT r.book_id 
                                 FROM reviews r  
                                 WHERE user_id = '4')
               ) AS Books_not_reviewed 
FROM reviews r
GROUP BY (r.user_id);
```

Apologies I am somewhat new to SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Postgres version 14.1

Comment: Please provide data as ***text***, never as image. Show your table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and Postgres version. I assume there is also come kind of `users` table ... And describe what the result should be, *exactly*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your query dynamic, if you make the `userid` as a parameter and use prepared statements.

Also, the below query can give you the list of all books *NOT* reviewed by each user, you can modify the query to suit your needs.

```
select u.userid, array( select bookid from books 
where bookid not in (select 
           bookid from reviews r 
            where r.userid=u.userid) )
    from users u
```